# cmake only sub directories based library

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, subdirectory

I am trying to figure out to create a small cmake file. The directory struture includes 4 sub folders and which has src and header files. There is no src or header file at root. All I want is to create a Shared library using cmake by compiling these four folders.
CMakeLists.txt at root

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.7)
Project(NEWPROJ)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_MAJOR_VERSION 00)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_MINOR_VERSION 01)
set(${PROJECT_NAME} 0)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION
  ${${PROJECT_NAME}_MAJOR_VERSION}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_MINOR_VERSION}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_PATCH_VERSION})
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SOVERSION ${${PROJECT_NAME}_MAJOR_VERSION}.${${PROJECT_NAME}_MINOR_VERSION})
Message ( Root )
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Folder1/include")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Folder2/include")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Folder3/include")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Folder4/include")

add_subdirectory ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Folder1")
add_subdirectory ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Folder2")
add_subdirectory ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Folder3")
add_subdirectory ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Folder4")

add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE} ${HEADERS})
```

CMakeLists.txt in Folder1

```
MESSAGE(Folder1)
set(SOURCE
   ${SOURCE}
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/file1.cc
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/file2.cpp
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/file3.cc
   PARENT_SCOPE
)

set(HEADERS
   ${HEADERS}
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/file1.h
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/file2.h
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/file3.h
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/file4.h
   PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

cmake .. successful

make folder1/src/file1.cc:1:20: fatal error: file1.h: No such file or directory

file1.cc

```
#include "file1.h"
```

...

Comment: I don't see how the problem could be caused from the code you've posted... if you could set up a small GitHub repository that causes the same problem that I can try to compile myself, that would be helpful.

Comment: get this double quotes are missing while doing include directories.
And no way to know other than banging head. No error from cmake.
I am also not so happy with the way I had to declare include_directories on root. Can I instead do it at every folder level?

Comment: Yep. So add in the missing close quotes.

Comment: Is it `Folder1` or `folder1`?